# how to retrieve fields from xml response

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I have following xml response:

```
String response =
+"<saml:AuthnStatement AuthnInstant=\"2016-12-14T12:22:26Z\" SessionIndex=\"s2f1ae3bd7397f10c6fd6b3b3f02d8b0611b2da501\">"
+"<saml:AuthnContext>"
+"<saml:AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport</saml:AuthnContextClassRef>"
                  +"</saml:AuthnContext>"
               +"</saml:AuthnStatement>"   
               +"<saml:AttributeStatement>"            
                  +"<saml:Attribute Name=\"uid\">"
                     +"<saml:AttributeValue xmlns:xs=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xsi:type=\"xs:string\">testing1</saml:AttributeValue>"
                  +"</saml:Attribute>"
                  +"<saml:Attribute Name=\"SecurityLevel\">"
                     +"<saml:AttributeValue xmlns:xs=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xsi:type=\"xs:string\">testing2</saml:AttributeValue>"
                  +"</saml:Attribute>"
                  +"<saml:Attribute Name=\"Culture\">"
                     +"<saml:AttributeValue xmlns:xs=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xsi:type=\"xs:string\">testing3</saml:AttributeValue>"
                  +"</saml:Attribute>"
                  +"<saml:Attribute Name=\"AuthMethod\">"
                     +"<saml:AttributeValue xmlns:xs=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xsi:type=\"xs:string\">testing4</saml:AttributeValue>"
                  +"</saml:Attribute>"
               +"</saml:AttributeStatement>"
            +"</saml:Assertion>";
```

Using ordinary string functions, substring, length, I can retreive data from fields. But it is long and unconvenient process..

How I can process this response using some java libraries and get info from fields?

Comment: You can use the OpenSAML library in order to process SAML messages. You can find documentation over [here](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/OpenSAML/Home)

Answer (score 2):

You need DOM Parser.

DOM parser parses the entire XML document and loads it into memory; then models it in a “TREE” structure for easy traversal or manipulation.

See example here:

https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/

Answer (score 0):

I use JDOM2. 
It's quite easy to manipulate : https://github.com/hunterhacker/jdom/wiki/JDOM2-A-Primer